# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package even with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to access a function in package1 from inside package 2

```
project
 |- __init__.py
 |- package1
   |-__init__.py
   |-module1.py
 |- package2
   |-__init__.py
   |-module2.py
```

package1/__init __.py

```
from .module1 import my_function

# I have also tried the following:
# from module1 import my_function
# from module1 import *
# import module1
# and also leaving this file empty
```

package2/module2.py

```
from ..package1 import my_function

# I have also already tried the following:
# from ..package1 import module1
# from .. package1 import module1
# from ..package1 import my_function
# from .. package1 import my_function
# import sys
# sys.path.append('.')

# import package1
```

Comment: As it turns out upon further research relative imports across packages are not allowed in Python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- leave package1/__init __.py empty
- in package2/module2.py, add: `from project.package1.module1 import my_function`
- in your terminal, set the parent directory of *project* as the current working directory and run: `python -m project.package2.module2` >> No error message, my_function outputs as expected